# JSON response getting clobbered by catch all URL and returned as 404 page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a React/Express setup like so (simplified for brevity):

```
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')

const CLIENT_BUILD_PATH = path.join(__dirname, '../build')

const serialize = data => JSON.stringify({ data })

const app = express()
app.use(express.static(CLIENT_BUILD_PATH))

app.get('/api/get/data', (request, response) => {
  Promise.resolve(loadData()).then(data => {
    console.log(data)
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    response.end(serialize(data))
  }).catch((error) => {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    response.end(serialize({}))
  })
})

// Catch all route
app.get('*', (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(path.join(CLIENT_BUILD_PATH, 'index.html'))
})
```

When the URL `/api/get/data` is accessed I would like to return plain JSON.

E.g.

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
}
```

However, what is returned is React's **404 page**.

The `loadData()` resolves just fine, I can see `data` logged in the console. But somehow the response is being overridden (or something) by the catch all route. I think anyways, I can't figure it out.

**Update**: `loadData()` is structured like so:

```
const loadData = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ...
    resolve(data)
  })
}
```

Comment: Show us your actual HTTP request, as shown in your browser's developers tools.  I bet it's not actually requesting `/api/get/data`...

Comment: He mentions he is able to see the console logged which is in the route. I presume he is getting into the route.

Comment: Can we see what `loadData()` is?

Comment: It's really long, I added the gist of it though.

Comment: I think it has something to do with how the routes are structured and/or how final pages are rendered, or something related to those. Because it does work and deliver JSON when I request it from the front end. (e.g. `const getRestaurants = async (context) => { const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/get/top-restaurants') const data = await res.json() return !!data ? data : {} }`) I thought maybe a fresh build would help but `yarn build` choked on a completely separate error that I don't have time to debug at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

ExpressJs has an abbreviated function for JSON responses. Use the `.json()` on a response to get the desired results, ex:

`response.json(data);`

Comment: Hmm, that still gives me the same response. Though I do get this warning in the console when I change it: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

Comment: This might be a side effect of using `writeHead()` I have in the past used syntax such as `res.status(400).json(data);` however 200 is the default status. I would try removing the `writeHead()` line and try only send like: `response.send(serialize(data))`

Comment: Also, after removing the `writeHead()` line, check the edit in my answer to use `response.json()` this will stringify your object as well so you don't have to include the `serialize(` function everywhere.

Comment: Well that didn't fix the 404 problem, but it did fix the problem that allows me to access the data from the front-end portion of my app. So I think I'll mark this as solved. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm.. I just realized my catch all routes are `app.use('/', ...)` and with no route at all. I wonder if the asterisk is over aggressive. *Updated answer to better indicated the catch all route.*

Comment: You can absolutely use `.end()`, which sends whatever data you put in, and subsequently closes the connection all in one go.

Comment: @Brad Cool, that's good to know. I've gone ahead and pulled that out to prevent confusion. I believe the poster would still better benefit from a `res.json()` so I've left that.